# On rebase, rebased-patches files grow exponentially in size

Tags: git, rebase

I have some strange behavior of Git on my new Laptop.

I have a huge git repo  (65GB+) with a lot of branches.
I init my new git folder with this repo and set `sparse.checkout` to true
Then I fetched  specific branch from `my-fork/branch` and run: `git checkout -b branch my-fork/branch` (the track remote message was printed by GIT)
Then I rebased my current work on `origin/master` branch (`git rebase master`)

I got next console message that is stuck on my screen: [image] for long time

Then I went to the .git folder and found that file with name `rebased-patches` size 23+ Gb [image]and it is grows exponentially until I got message that I out of space on my HDD.

I am using GIT day by day, but never met such strange behavior

Any suggestions what is wrong with it?
Maybe something on its init I did wrong?

Comment: Just to be clear, you have a 5 _terabyte_ git repo? What's the size of the working copy you check out? If it's hundreds of gigabytes, sure, you might have this happen as part of "normal" operation during a rebase.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Git really isn't designed to handle anything close to 5TB.  Have you considered Git-LFS?

Comment: Yeah; I would love to see some details about your repository.  Given the hoops we had to jump through to support a "mere" 300 GB working directory (http://GVFS.io), I'd love to know more about your setup!

Comment: My mistake guys... it is 65GB. Sorry for such stupid mistake (it is  midnight here and I broke my head to solve this issue)...  @msanford maybe it is sounds weird, but on my job PC it is not stuck like here.. it is 30 seconds and rebase is done

Comment: sparseCheckout only affects the working directory (not the repo) - are you talking about the working directory size, or the repo size? (edit : never mind - ic)

Comment: @AlexBerd No problem, thanks for the update! I can't think of a reason off the top of my head, but someone better in git than I probably will.

Comment: This sounds like the expected sequence of commits within the rebase is no where near the size that Git actually finds.

Comment: Check for the mergebase of the master and HEAD that you implicitly rebase (chek the manual, rebase has a funny command line!). View it with gitk to be sure that the fork point is where you expect. etc.